# Warnings in kubeadm after migrating from docker to containerd

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubeadm, containerd

I run a kubernetes cluster, installed with `kubeadm`. I recently upgraded from 1.19 to 1.20 and migrated the container runtime from `docker` to `containerd`, since `docker` is now deprecated.

I configured `containerd` and `kubelet` to use it, and uninstalled `docker` from all nodes. Everything seems to be running fine.

Today, I tried to upgrade from 1.20 to 1.21 but I got two warnings when running `kubeadm upgrade plan` which make me think the `containerd` transition was not complete:

- It tries to use docker:

  ```
  cannot automatically set CgroupDriver when starting the Kubelet: cannot execute 'docker info -f {{.CgroupDriver}}': executable file not found in $PATH
  ```

  - I probably have a configuration issue because `kubeadm` seems to not be aware that we don't use docker anymore, but I haven't found the right option in the documentation or local conf, except `--cri-socket` which doesn't work with `kubeadm upgrade`.
  - Second, the wording is strange: "when starting the Kubelet". But my kubelet is starting just fine, doesn't complain about missing docker or CgroupDriver.
- It doesn't detect the cgroup driver setting:

  ```
  The 'cgroupDriver' value in the KubeletConfiguration is empty. Starting from 1.22, 'kubeadm upgrade' will default an empty value to the 'systemd' cgroup driver. The cgroup driver between the container runtime and the kubelet must match!
  ```

  This is really surprising because I have `cgroupDriver: systemd` in `kubectl -n kube-system get cm kubelet-config-1.20 -o yaml`, in `/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml`, also the flag in `/etc/default/kubelet` and `/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env`, and it is even printed by `kubeadm --v=10` !

How can I find out if there is an underlying configuration issue, or is I can safely ignore these warnings ?

I'm not sure what files, configmap or logs may be useful to help me solve this, but I will gladly provide them if needed.

Comment: Downvoting without telling why is kind of rude :\

Comment: After investigating further, I found this is not only a warning but an hard error for `kubeadm upgrade apply`. Seems related to issue https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/2364

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this was downvoted, in the event that someone has the same issue and feels as lost as I was, I hope google will lead you here :)

- `kubeadm` was trying to use `docker` based on the node's configuration and not the kubelet's configuration, and I didn't change the nodes' config when migrating to `containerd` (as I was not aware it was set at that level). Fix with:

  ```
  kubectl annotate node $node --overwrite kubeadm.alpha.kubernetes.io/cri-socket=unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock
  ```

  for each node. Found this [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/2364#issuecomment-757038532)
- The `cgroupDriver` warning is a [bug](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/2443) in `kubeadm` that probably won't be fixed because the whole check is going away soon. So it can be ignored (if your kubelet's conf really sets the cgrouDriver).